# Recommended way of copying an Excel table with indicators to PowerPoint

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I have an Excel file with a few charts and the attached dashboard (as can be seen in the image).

[image: Dashboard]

I am copying the charts objects from Excel to PowerPoint, but not sure what is the best way of copying the attached dashboard to PowerPoint, as it consists of a range of Excel cells, some Indicators using Conditional Formatting, and a circle object.

I don't want to copy it as a picture, because then it looks like it's out-of-focus in PowerPoint.

I have added a section of my code (not the whole thing as it's very long), just want to know the method of copying this dashboard image.

```
  Public Sub UpdatePowerPoint(PowerPointFile)

'Add a reference to the Microsoft PowerPoint Library by:
'1. Go to Tools in the VBA menu
'2. Click on Reference
'3. Scroll down to Microsoft PowerPoint X.0 Object Library, check the box, and press Okay

Dim ppProgram                           As PowerPoint.Application
Dim ppPres                              As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim ppFullPath                          As String
Dim ppName                              As String
Dim activeSlide                         As PowerPoint.Slide

Dim cht                                 As Excel.ChartObject
Dim cht_count                           As Integer
Dim myShape                             As Object
Dim myChart                             As Object
Dim SlideNum, GPLRank                   As Integer
Dim ProjectIPPNum, ProjectName          As String
Dim ShapeNum                            As Integer
Dim ExpenseActual, ExpenseBalance       As Long

Dim StageStat                           As String
Dim nextKD                              As String
Dim shapeStageStat                      As Shape

On Error Resume Next
Set ppProgram = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

ppFullPath = PowerPointFile

If ppProgram Is Nothing Then
    Set ppProgram = New PowerPoint.Application
    i = 1
Else
    If ppProgram.Presentations.Count > 0 Then
        ppName = Mid(ppFullPath, InStrRev(ppFullPath, "\") + 1, Len(ppFullPath))
        i = 1
        ppCount = ppProgram.Presentations.Count
        Do Until i = ppCount + 1
            If ppProgram.Presentations.Item(i).Name = ppName Then
                Set ppPres = ppProgram.Presentations.Item(i)
                GoTo OnePager_Pres_Found
            Else
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Loop
    End If
End If

ppProgram.Presentations.Open Filename:=PowerPointFile  ' 'PowerPointFile = "C:\Test.pptx"
Set ppPres = ppProgram.Presentations.Item(i)

OnePager_Pres_Found:
ppPres.Windows(1).Activate  ' activate the One-Pager Presentation in case you have several open, and the One_pager is currently not the app "on-focus"

' loop through all PowerPoint Slides, and copy all Chart objects from Excel
For ProjectCounter = 0 To NumberofProjectShts
    Worksheets(ProjectShtName(ProjectCounter)).Activate

    GPLRank = ActiveSheet.Cells(12, 2)
    SlideNum = ActiveSheet.Cells(24, 2)
    ProjectIPPNum = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 2)
    ProjectName = ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 2)
    StageStat = ActiveSheet.Cells(20, 2)
    nextKD = ActiveSheet.Cells(18, 2)
    ExpenseActual = ActiveSheet.Cells(33, 4)
    ExpenseBalance = ActiveSheet.Cells(33, 5)

    On Error GoTo Error_PPTSlideNum_Handler
    ppProgram.ActivePresentation.Slides(SlideNum).Select

    Set myShape = ppProgram.ActivePresentation.Slides(SlideNum).Shapes

    ' --- loop throughout the Slide shapes and search for the Shape of type chart, then delete the old ones
    For i = myShape.Count To 1 Step -1
        If myShape.Item(i).HasChart Or myShape.Item(i).Type = msoEmbeddedOLEObject Or myShape.Item(i).Type = msoPicture Then
           myShape.Item(i).Delete
        Else
            If myShape.Item(i).Left > 600 Then
                myShape.Item(i).Delete
            Else
                Select Case myShape.Item(i).AutoShapeType
                    Case msoShapeOval, msoShapeOctagon, msoShapeIsoscelesTriangle
                        myShape.Item(i).Delete
                End Select
            End If
        End If
    Next

    'Show the PowerPoint
    ppProgram.Visible = True

    ' select the 1-Pager Slide number which we will update the charts with the Excel Charts
    Set activeSlide = ppProgram.ActivePresentation.Slides(SlideNum)

    ' --- copy the dasboard (with Stage Status indicator) from Excel to Powerpoint , as Embedded Excel object ---
    ' this is the part I've added to copy the dashboard from Excel to PowerPoint slide
    Columns("F:G").ColumnWidth = 7.71
    Columns("H:J").ColumnWidth = 4.71
    Rows("1:4").RowHeight = 18.75

    ActiveSheet.Range("F1:J4").Copy ' .Select

    ' Paste to PowerPoint and position
    Set myShape = ppProgram.ActivePresentation.Slides(SlideNum).Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteMetafilePicture, msoFalse)
    ' Set Dashboard object properties:
    myShape.Left = 536 ' 7.44"
    myShape.Top = 7 ' 0.1"

    ' --- Loop through each chart in the Excel worksheet and paste them into the PowerPoint ---
    For Each cht In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
        'go to the 1-Pager Slide number where we will update the charts with the Excel Charts
        Set activeSlide = ppProgram.ActivePresentation.Slides(SlideNum)

        'Copy the chart and paste it into the PowerPoint as a Metafile Picture
        cht.Select
        ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy

        If cht.Name = "RiskRadar_Chart" Then  ' change paste setting only for Radar type chart, to look nicer in PowerPoint
            Set myChart = ppProgram.ActivePresentation.Slides(SlideNum).Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteMetafilePicture, msoFalse)
        Else
            Set myChart = ppProgram.ActivePresentation.Slides(SlideNum).Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteDefault, msoFalse) 'ppPasteShape
        End If

        'Adjust the positioning of the Chart on Powerpoint Slide , each inch is 72 points
        Select Case cht.Name
            Case "Timeline_Chart" '  1 ' Timeline Chart
                myChart.Left = 11 ' 0.16"
                myChart.Top = 403 ' 5.55"

            Case "Budget_Chart" ' 2 ' Man-Hours Chart
                myChart.Left = 387 ' 5.37"
                myChart.Top = 284 ' 3.94"

            Case "Expense_Chart"   ' 3 ' Expense Chart
                myChart.Left = 387 ' 5.37"
                myChart.Top = 347 ' 4.81"

            Case "RiskRadar_Chart" ' 4 ' Risk-Radar Chart
                myChart.Left = 449 ' 6.23"
                myChart.Top = 7 ' 0.1"

        End Select
    Next

    ' --- Add Stage Status indicator with Next KD text inside (except PARK) ----
    Select Case StageStat
        Case "Green"
            With activeSlide.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, 652, 16, 32, 32) ' Left, Top , Width ,Height
                .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 128, 0) ' color Green
                .Fill.Solid
                .Line.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorText1
                .Line.Weight = 0.75

                .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.color.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0) ' Shape Text Color
                .TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text = nextKD    ' Text inside Shape
                .TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 14  ' Adjust Font Size
                .TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Name = "Arial"  ' Adjust Font Style
                .TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignCenter  ' Center Align Text
                .TextFrame2.VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle   ' Vertically Align Text to Middle
                .TextFrame2.MarginLeft = 0
                .TextFrame2.MarginRight = 0
            End With

        Case "Yellow"
            With activeSlide.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 652, 16, 32, 32)  ' Left, Top , Width ,Height
                .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0) ' color Yellow
                .Fill.Solid
                .Line.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorText1
                .Line.Weight = 0.75

                .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.color.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0) ' Shape Text Color
                .TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text = nextKD    ' Text inside Shape
                .TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 14  ' Adjust Font Size
                .TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Name = "Arial"  ' Adjust Font Style
                .TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignCenter  ' Center Align Text
                .TextFrame2.VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle   ' Vertically Align Text to Middle
                .TextFrame2.MarginLeft = 0
                .TextFrame2.MarginRight = 0
            End With

        Case "Red"
            With activeSlide.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeIsoscelesTriangle, 652, 16, 36, 36)  ' Left, Top , Width ,Height
                .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' color Red
                .Fill.Solid
                .Line.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorText1
                .Line.Weight = 0.75

                .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.color.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0) ' Shape Text Color
                .TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text = nextKD    ' Text inside Shape
                .TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 14  ' Adjust Font Size
                .TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Name = "Arial"  ' Adjust Font Style
                .TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignCenter  ' Center Align Text
                .TextFrame2.VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle   ' Vertically Align Text to Middle
                .TextFrame2.MarginLeft = 0
                .TextFrame2.MarginRight = 0
                .TextFrame2.Column.Number = 2
            End With
    End Select

Error_PPTSlideNum_Handler:
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Err.Clear
    MsgBox "Project " & ProjectName & " Slide Number " & SlideNum & " not found in selected PowerPoint. " & _
            vbCrLf & "Update your Slide Number according to it's position.", vbInformation, "PowerPoint Slide Number Error"
End If

Next ' ProjectCounter = 0 To NumberofProjectShts

AppActivate ("Microsoft PowerPoint")
Set activeSlide = Nothing
Set ppProgram = Nothing
Set ppPres = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you upload a sample dashboard file. If it has confidential data you can sanitize it. It will help in chalking out optimum strategy for coding.

Comment: Further to my previous comment, it will be better if you upload total sheet intended to be exported to PPT slide after sanitizing it for confidential data.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the sample example shown here. Lot of effort goes to properly naming the ranges for various parameters which is done in Excel worksheet. I have also shown a snapshot of the name manager to give you an idea and also the snapshot of final output of the dashboard in the PowerPoint.

```
Option Explicit

Dim PP As Object
Dim PP_File As Object
Dim PP_Slide As Object

Private Sub CopyandPastetoPPT(myRangeName As String, myTitle As String, myScaleHeight As Single, myScaleWidth As Single)
Dim NextShape As Integer
Dim ReportDate As String

    ReportDate = Range("myReportDate").Value & " / Week " & Range("myReportWeek").Value & " - "
    Application.GoTo Reference:=myRangeName
    Selection.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
    Range("A1").Select
    PP.ActivePresentation.Slides.Add PP.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, 11
    Set PP_Slide = PP_File.Slides(PP.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count)
    PP_Slide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = ReportDate & myTitle
    NextShape = PP_Slide.Shapes.Count + 1
    PP_Slide.Shapes.PasteSpecial 2
    PP_Slide.Shapes(NextShape).ScaleHeight myScaleHeight, 1
    PP_Slide.Shapes(NextShape).ScaleWidth myScaleWidth, 1
    PP_Slide.Shapes(NextShape).Left = PP_File.PageSetup.SlideWidth \ 2 - PP_Slide.Shapes(NextShape).Width \ 2
    PP_Slide.Shapes(NextShape).Top = 90
End Sub



Sub ExportToPPT()
Dim ActFileName As Variant
Dim ScaleFactor As Single

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandling
    ActFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Microsoft PowerPoint-Files (*.ppt), *.ppt")
    ScaleFactor = Range("myScaleFactor").Value
    Set PP = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
    If ActFileName = False Then
        PP.Activate
        PP.Presentations.Add
        Set PP_File = PP.ActivePresentation
    Else
        PP.Activate
        Set PP_File = PP.Presentations.Open(ActFileName)
    End If
    PP.Visible = True
    CopyandPastetoPPT "myDashboard01", Range("myInputStartTitles").Offset(1, 0).Value, ScaleFactor, ScaleFactor

    Set PP_Slide = Nothing
    Set PP_File = Nothing
    Set PP = Nothing
    Worksheets(1).Activate
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandling:

    Set PP_Slide = Nothing
    Set PP_File = Nothing
    Set PP = Nothing
    MsgBox "Error No.: " & Err.Number & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Description: " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"

End Sub
```

[image: Excel dashboard sheet with name manager]
[image: PowerPoint Slide for dashboard]

Comment: I was able to handle this (during Sunday). I tried running your code from Excel anyway, just to give it a try, but the open file dialog won't display any PowerPoint files.

Comment: @Shai Rado File dialog box opens for asking a existing file but if you cancel it then it will go to make new PPT file. I set reference Microsoft PowerPoint Object 16.0 library also( I have Excel 2016). I have verified again and it works fine for me. Since you have already worked out the solution it makes me happy. Goodluck to you -Cheers-)